# Method to classify and recode high and low probability regions?

Tags: classification

Most classification methods typically train and predict over all instances, possibly giving a less efficient answer. To give an example, imagine two randomly populated regions on a 2D grid (both populated with the same two binary classes). One well defined space (let's say top half) has 80% of positive classes, and the other only 50%. Further, assume these probabilities are stable.

I envision some type of learner like a classification tree could identify the regions using entropy based splitting. But rather than merging more noisy sets, I would want to literally prune or recode the more noisy regions to a 3rd class as a method to pre-process for the prediction step.
So that rather than getting a low average prediction across all of the exemplars, my learner could focus more on high regions of probability. Does anyone know of such an existing method?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the focus of active learning. Do watch this video by Sanjoy Dasgupta, John Langford: http://videolectures.net/icml09_dasgupta_langford_actl/ to understand the framework. In a way, it combines unsupervised learning(understanding the locality structure) with semi-supervised learning and label propagation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I don't really see that as solving the problem. As I understand it, he is still classifying two to n distinct classes over the original region of interest (by sampling over smaller subsets and inferring discrimination boundaries), but never actually identifying then discarding or recoding previously classified low probability regions.

Comment: @pat I haven't watched the video. But as Praneeth says this is the point of active learning. You may want to google ' Uncertainty sampling'. I think that is what you want to achieve. P.S: and I just realised the question is three years old, not of much help now I suppose :)