# Are there any known methods for picking out the "easy" cases for classification?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

Suppose I have positive and negative samples, and I care a lot more about precision than recall. Furthermore, I assume that there are some cases among the positive samples which are "easier" to separate than others, but I have no direct way of identifying these. By easier, I mean it is easy to pick for a given classifier to pick them out without picking any negative samples. 
If we only had two input features, we would be able to visually pick these out as the positive examples which are visibly non-overlapping with the negative examples, but in this case I am working in high-dimensional spaces.

Is there some algorithm that will, given a set of input features and labels, identify those cases which are "easy" to classify?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34910/method-to-classify-and-recode-high-and-low-probability-regions I am interested as well.  One method I mean to look into more is known as bump hunting (Friedman, J. H. and Fisher, N. I. (1999). Bump-hunting for high dimensional data. Statistics
and Computing, 9, 123{143.).

Comment: @pat I think maybe my answer poses something to tackle your question too.

Comment: @JEquihua thanks. I will read the paper soon. Looks interesting.

Comment: You may want to take a look at here: http://homepages.cwi.nl/~wmkoolen/easydata2013/

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for sounds a tad like Evidence Trees:

> Evidence Trees. We have developed a new approach to supervised
>   learning in which ensembles of tree classifiers are applied not to
>   make classification decisions but to select which training data points
>   provide evidence relevant to making a decision or prediction. This
>   evidence can then be input to a second-level decision making process,
>   which could be another classifier or some form of kernel density
>   estimation.

Which is being developed by Thomas G. Dietterich. [This](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/) is his webpage. I think he originally used it for arthropod species identification through their pictures (BugID project). You can also consult it on his webpage or directly [here](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/bugid/).